# What is the meaning of this sentence from "A Study in Scarlet" by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I had neither kith nor kin in England, and was therefore as free as air -- or as free as an income of eleven shillings and sixpence a day will permit a man to be. **Under such circumstances I naturally gravitated to London, that great
>   cesspool into which all the loungers and idlers of the Empire are
>   irresistibly drained.**

It is not quite clear to me what "gravitated to London" means. The rest of the sentence isn't particularly clear either. Please explain.

Comment: [**Gravitate**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gravitate) - to have a natural tendency or be strongly attracted (usually followed by to or toward): *Musicians gravitate toward one another.* Thus, the situation was such that it was natural for me to be attracted to London. Metaphorically, London exherts a "gravitational attraction" that draws loungers, idlers, dossers, ne'er-do-wells towards it. Also metaphorically, it's like a foul drain that worthless people like that sink down into.

Comment: @Ricky nice edits on the question, more context

Comment: you do know what gravity is, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

The author is saying that as a free person with **minimal responsibility**, he was attracted to London with all the **good** and **bad** adventures London had to offer, but hinting at the **darker side** of life.

> **gravitated to London**

means **attracted to**, **drawn to**, the author is saying these types of people **naturally** and move towards this destination (London) just as **gravity** is a natural (an irresistible) force

> **that great cesspool**

A **cesspool** is a pool (or pond) of **human waste** (both solid and liquid), referring to something as a **cesspool** means it has undesirable qualities, in this case there is a **moral** context

> **loungers and idlers**

refers to types of people that are socially undesirable, those that **do nothing** and do not contribute to society

> **of the Empire**

refers to the once mighty **English Empire**(commonly referred to post the Acts of Union as the **British Empire**) of which London was (and still is) its capital and largest city

> **irresitibly drained**

**Draining** is a process driven by **gravity**, "**draining** water from a bathtub".  It means the undesirable people are removed from other parts of the geographically spread Empire and **drained into** (or concentrated into) London.  In this usage **irresitible** means **can not be stopped**.

The author is saying that London, being the major city of the Empire, attracted many different types of people especially **undesirable ones**, as any major city in the world still does. Please keep in mind this is a picture of a **Dickensian** London.  The author's attraction for adventure is as a **moth to a flame**.

Answer (score 3):

There are two metaphors here.

**Metaphor One**

The narrator had no reason to settle down anywhere: he had no family and no friends. He had a small income that allowed him to spend as much time as he liked without looking for a job. He had nothing to do. The implication here is that he was, at that point of his life and career, a drifter: moving around without purpose, like a rogue asteroid in interstellar space.

A large space object - like a planet or a star - can attract such an asteroid, which will thereupon *gravitate* towards it. In the British Empire, London is that planet (or star) for all drifters.

**Metaphor Two**

The second metaphor compares London to a cesspool: an underground storage space into which all kinds of waste is drained. Loungers and idlers are being compared to waste drained into a cesspool, and London to a cesspool. This view is complimentary neither to idlers nor London, but it was very popular among England's upper middle class towards the end of the 19th Century: the very group that was to constitute the vast majority of Sir Arthur's readers.

Comment: *Gravitated* could just be a part of the cesspool metaphor, the waste flowing downhill.

Comment: @TRomano: Yeah, but that would put London at the bottom of the imperial gravity well. Generally speaking, the opening pages of the saga are neither well-written nor imaginative. Sir Arthur is trying too hard, I think, imitating his  more successful (at that point) colleagues, almost groveling for approval - up until the appearance of the hero.

Answer (score 0):

I would submit that the first part of the statement is a self-justification for indulging in the life-style of the idle. He stipulates that he has no purpose in life. Why not join the flow?